# Python Write to File taking Long Time

Tags: python

I have 2 Python3.7.3 programs that are essentially doing the same writing to a file. One program does it almost instantaneously while the other takes a relatively long time.

Program 1:

```
t = time.localtime() 
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time)      
sptxt = open('output.txt','w')
print(str) 
sptxt.write(str)
sptxt.close()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time)   

Results:
22:32:33
right right 
22:32:33
```

Program 2

```
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time)
ans = (ds.stt(audio))
sptxt = open('output.txt','w')
print(ans)
sptxt.write(ans)
sptxt.close()
t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
print(current_time) 


Results:
22:50:25
 riht riht
22:50:32
```

Don't understand why there is such a time difference

Comment: You're timing more than the file write in Program 2.  If you put in a time output right after the call to ds.stt, you can see how much time that operation takes.

Comment: there is no line like this in program 2 ans = (ds.stt(audio))